# Should I end all definitions from packages with semicolon?

Tags: packages, coding-style

I noticed that if I open a `.m` file in Mathematica and click on the `Run Package` button, all the `Set` definitions will be printed as output if they are not ended in `;`. The same for `function::usage` definitions.

This is probably harmless, but I am wondering if there is a guidance on weather semicolons should be appended at the end of `Set` or `SetDelayed` definitions.

Looking into the Mathematica libraries source code, I can see both approaches - some `Module` functions have `;` at the end, others do not.

Comment: As you noticed, it doesn't really make a difference for as long as the commands written in the package don't print any output as a side effect.  Packages typically contain definitions, which don't print anything when evaluated, so most of the time there's no need for semicolons.  `Set` is a possible exception, as you noticed.

Comment: I usually do this, but I know a lot of folks who don't.  This probably doesn't matter much, as long as one is consistent with it.

Comment: @Szabolcs `Set` doesn't print if the package is read in via `<<` or `Needs`

Answer (score 2):

(Based on Szabolcs's & rm -rf's comment)

As you noticed, it doesn't really make a difference for as long as the commands written in the package don't print any output as a side effect. Packages typically contain definitions, which don't print anything when evaluated directly, so most of the time there's no need for semicolons. `Set` is a possible exception, as you noticed.

Even cells in the package which contain code that otherwise prints output if <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>-ing the cell (e.g. lines with `Set`, or simple statements without assignments like `{1, 2, 3}`) won't print anything if the package is read in via `<<` or `Needs`.