# Is there a guideline about when to end expressions with semicolons?

Tags: coding-style

Whether for nested `If`s or within scoping constructs like `Module` and `Block`, I never know whether to end the final expression with a semicolon. I know the semicolon suppresses output, but, for example, in a series of nested `If`s, one needs only to semicolon the outermost `If` to suppress output.

So, is it better practice to semicolon *everything* unless output is needed? Or is it better to semicolon *nothing* until the last point where output is unwanted?

Comment: I tend to put it everywhere I don't expect desired output: saves me from the "where'd that `Null` come from" and the "surprise multiplications" problems...

Comment: This clearly depends on the expression. For example, you can't just write `If[x < 1, y = 1 z = 3 , y = 4 ]` without a `;` between `y=1` and `z=3`. Even if you have the `z=3` in a new line in the notebook. One still needs a `;`

Comment: @Nasser - That's why I said the "final" expression—I mean the last expression before exiting a bracket.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/3066) helpful.

Comment: @m_goldberg I forgot about that answer!  Do you think this should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks, @m_goldberg. Mr.Wizard, I'd not be opposed to this being closed. FWIW though, your answer does address the specific point of style (_"There is little point in sprinkling `;` around your code without need [...]"_) which the other thread does not.

Comment: @acheong87 I added a section to my answer to better explain what I think `;` *is* useful for.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Related: [(33861)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33861/121)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I may be missing the point of this question, but I think it is important to note that `;` is the short form of [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html), and it is not primarily for suppressing output.

You can see how `;` is interpreted using one of the methods I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121):

```
HoldForm @ FullForm[a; b; c]
HoldForm @ FullForm[a; b;]
```

> ```
> CompoundExpression[a, b, c]
> CompoundExpression[a, b, Null]
> ```

Note that when a final expression is omitted `Null` is inserted, just like this behavior with `,`:

```
{1, 2,}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, Null}
> ```

The suppression of output is not a behavior of `CompoundExpression` but rather `Null`, which when returned as output (alone) is not printed.  For example `2 Null/2` evaluates to `Null`, therefore when given as input no output is printed.

There is little point in sprinkling `;` around your code without need, unless perhaps as a visual reminder that the evaluated form of a given expression is not directly used by the surrounding head.  One exception is when writing code that will eventually be made into a function or `Module` as line breaks are not valid separators in this case, therefore even functions that already return `Null` such as `SetDelayed` should be terminated with a `;`, e.g.:

```
foo[bar_Integer] := bar^2;
foo[bar_Real]    := bar/2;
```

This avoids the error seen with:

```
Module[{foo},
  foo[bar_Integer] := bar^2
  foo[bar_Real]    := bar/2
]
```

---

#### What `;` is really for

The actual function of `CompoundExpression` is described in the documentation:

> *expr*<sub>1</sub>;*expr*<sub>2</sub>; ...
>    evaluates the expr<sub>i</sub> in turn, giving the last one as the result.

`CompoundExpression`, while more succinct and canonical than other methods, is not the only way to accomplish this.  For example you could use

```
Last[{expr1, expr2, ...}]
```

in the same manner, e.g.:

```
a = 5; b = a^2; Binomial[b, a]
Last[{a = 5, b = a^2, Binomial[b, a]}]
```

> ```
> 53130
>
> 53130
> ```

And suppression of output:

> ```
> x = Range@500;           
> Last[{x = Range@500,}]   (* no output printed *)
> ```

You can also return a specific expression using [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) in a simple [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html):

```
#2 &[a = 5, b = a^2, Binomial[b, a]]
```

> ```
> 25
> ```

This is specifically appropriate when you need to perform some action after generating an expression, such as closing a stream:

```
str = StringToStream["abcdefg 123456"];
# &[Read[str, Word], Close @ str]
```

> ```
> "abcdefg"
> ```

I would be remiss not to mention that these alternative methods are not actually equivalent to `CompoundExpression` because even though they only *return* one expression (possibly `Null`) they still accumulate all of them in memory.  Compare these, each pair of lines run in a fresh Kernel:

```
Range@1*^7; Range@1*^7; Range@1*^7; Range@1*^7;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 94923152
> ```

```
Last[{Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7,}]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 174925336
> ```

To get the memory performance of `;` one would need something more complex, such as:

```
SetAttributes[ce, HoldAll]
ce[x__] := Fold[#2 &, , Hold @ x]

ce[Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7, Range@1*^7,]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 93506816
> ```

---

Additional reading:

- [Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter (Pitfalls)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/121)

Comment: So when are you going to write that *Mathematica* book. I would love to read it :)

Comment: @RunnyKine ["I've been studying the mystery of *Mathematica* for years; someday I'll publish my book: A Century of Studying *Mathematica* by Mr.Wizard, volume one The Early Years."](https://www.engywook.com/static/frontend/images/engywook-hd.png) :^)

Comment: Please, I'm curious to see the evolution of this amazing tool from someone who has studied it well before it became available :)

Comment: @RunnyKine In case you didn't get the reference: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088323/ -- worth a viewing, even as an adult.  (And my point was: when I've been using *Mathematica* that long I may finally be qualified to write a book about it.)

Comment: I've seen it a few times when I was much younger :). In any case, I'm pretty sure you're more than qualified to write one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Thanks for all the examples! Perfectly clear to me now.