# Why is this semicolon in red?

Tags: warning-messages, syntax-highlighting

I have a piece of code that works well, but when I put a semicolon after a plotting statement, the semicolon appears in red. What's the error?

[image]

Comment: It's not about the `Print`, it's just that you prevent a `Plot` to be plotted, so it appears red.

Comment: @oska OK, I believed that if a line is Plot, Print,.... or similar with an output semicolos is accepted and the result will be showed

Comment: @oska Thank you but... should be semicolon of Print in RED too?

Comment: It's all about `Plot` not being plotted I guess. With or without `;`, `Print` is printed. Check [this](http://i.imgur.com/3kVhEpB.png).

Comment: @oska Thank you, Oska Very illustrative

Comment: Your screenshot is *really* tiny and hard to read.

Comment: @YvesKlett the actual screenshot is of a sensible size, but it gets resized to fit the narrow column allowed for the question. (IMO, in the era of ubiquitous widescreen displays, it looks silly to leave a huge white space either side of the site content and use only a third or a quarter of the screen area for anything useful, but I suppose there must be a reason for it.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. in any case the displayed version is neigh unreadable unless magnified. Agreed on the ample whitespace though.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: That reason is typography. Most typographers agree that somewhere around 45-75 characters per line is optimal for long passages. The web has spoiled us somewhat in that regard - we've now grown more accustomed to wider measures (and unserifed faces). For instance, StackExchange, on my system, renders at about 100 characters per line, which is really near the border of too wide a measure.

Comment: @Reid I don't doubt that what you're saying is correct. But there are many problems with that as an explanation--as you pointed out, the choice of a sans serif font for one. And there is obviously no attempt at tracking or kerning either. But the more pressing issues, I would say, are: StackExchange posts rarely contain long passages of text; and pictures are not text anyway, so restricting them to the space allowed for text seems to make little sense. So, while you might well be right, if this is really the explanation, it IMO has the air of cargo-cultism about it.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Well, I don't want to get in a protracted discussion about this, but an unserifed face was chosen because serif faces tend to look poor at low DPI (computer monitors), so I don't think that's a "problem" with the argument. As for tracking and kerning, those are problems with the host system's font rendering mostly - on my end, it looks pretty good (though not perfect). Last, on the SE sites I frequent, long passages are pretty frequent, actually; these comments are a simple example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a syntax mistake. Consider it a suggestion, `FrontEnd` tells you: "maybe you want to plot it as it has no much sense now".

Of course it may have sense, it's just a suggestion.

If you take a closer look you will find that storing such `Plot` makes more sense for `FE`:

> [image]

Answer (score 25):

#### A bit of historic background

Before *Mathematica* version 6 graphics were produced as a side-effect much as `Print` works now.  In fact you can load this old system using:

```
<< Version5`Graphics`
```

Now you get this behavior:

[image]

Note that the output is `- Graphics -` and the plot itself is handled like `Print`.  Since there was often little value in having `- Graphics -` output it was common to see plot statements terminated with a semicolon, which returns `Null` [which is not written](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41091/121) to the Notebook.

In version 6 syntax highlighting of that trailing semicolon was added to remind people that with it no output at all would be produced, since the `Graphics` object is no longer printed as a side-effect.