# Having problems with ListPlot and a PaddedForm wrapper

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I defined a function `f[x_] = x^3  2 x`. Then I had to construct a table showing vertically, the values of `f` corresponding to x on the interval [-3,3] in increment of 0.5.

So, I did this:

```
f[x_] = x^3 - 2 x;
a := PaddedForm[x, {2, 1}];
b := PaddedForm[f[x], {5, 3}];
p = Table[{a, b}, {x, -3, 3, .5}];
TableForm[p, 
  TableHeadings -> {None,{"x", "f(x)=x^3-2x"}}, 
  TableAlignments -> Center]
```

I had my answers and so far it was ok. But next, I had to plot the set of values with heavy dots. So I did this:

```
ListPlot[p];
```

But now there's an error saying:

> Co-ordinate -3.0 in {-3.0,-21.000} is not a floating-point number ....

How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove the `PaddedForm` wrapper: `ListPlot[Table[{x, f@x}, {x, -3, 3, .5}]]`.

Comment: @Öskå You reply or Community Wiki or something? :)

Comment: ahahah, I'm on it! Wiki!

Answer (score 3):

In the [PaddedForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PaddedForm.html) documentation you can find:

> PaddedForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation.

This means that `PaddedForm` is just an inert wrapper which does not evaluate to something numeric. `ListPlot` requires numbers but after wrapping a number with `PaddedForm` or any other inert wrapper it does not a number anymore. One could check it with `NumberQ`:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
NumberQ /@ {PaddedForm[1, {2, 1}], g[2], Hold[3], 1[4]}
```

> ```
> {False, False, False, False}
> ```

Of course `ListPlot` will not display anything when a list containing no numbers is passed to it.

The following will work:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - 2 x;
ListPlot[Table[{x, f@x}, {x, -3, 3, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That might explain why I can't even upvote my own CW answer :(

Comment: @Öskå Your interpretation of the Documentation statement is not correct: `Plot`ting in *Mathematica* generally does not imply displaying or printing anything at all! The reason for the error message is clear: a number wrapped by arbitrary `Head` is not a number anymore. Instead of `PaddedForm` there could be any other inert wrapper, for example `g` or `Hold` or even a number like this: `1[1]`. Try `ListPlot[{g[1], Hold[2], 1[1]}]` - nothing is displayed because there are no numbers in the list! One could check it with `NumberQ`: `NumberQ /@ {g[1], Hold[2], 1[1]}` gives `{False, False, False}`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov that's the reason why it's a Community Wiki :) But thanks for the info :) I based my assumptions on [that answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47123/1356).

Comment: @Öskå That answer is correct and does not contradict me in any sense. One thing that will help you to understand that answer deeper is that now FrontEnd is able to render `Graphics` directly but before *Mathematica* 6 FrontEnd was able to render only PostScript and Bitmap graphics and the Kernel converted `Graphics` to PostScript for the purposes of displaying in the FrontEnd. That complicated things a bit. Also `Graphics` and "graphics" has different meanings when speaking about *Mathematica*.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info and for correcting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

With your `p`

```
ListPlot[First /@ # & /@ p]
```

[image]

Comment: F.Y.I.: `Map[First, p, {2}]` replaces the `First /@ # /@ p` :)

Comment: @Öskå, Thank you.