# The problem of For+RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

I type the following code in Mathematica 11:

```
For[n = 1, n <= 3, n++,
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < n, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
]
```

Then I press Shift+Enter, but Mathematica does not output any figures. Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a common mistake for users new to *Mathematica*, or coming from earlier versions.  Plots return `Graphics` expressions rather than displaying them as side-effects.  See [(47123)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47123/121).  You could add `Print` but generally a better method is to replace `For` with `Table`:  `Table[RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < n, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], {n, 1, 3}]`.  You can further format that output with `Column` or `GraphicsColumn` as desired, or animate it with `ListAnimate`.

Comment: Note: does there exist a canonical Q&A on this issue?  If not I think a post should be made in [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121) regarding this, as it has come up quite often.

Comment: Mr.Wizard: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what your aim. If it is just to 'print' 3 graphics:

```
For[n = 1, n <= 3, n++, 
 Print@RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < n, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

If you want an object you can use and refer to:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3
rps=RegionPlot[f[x, y] < #, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] & /@ Range[3]
```

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) is also a useful link with respect to loops in Mathematica.

Comment: ubpdqn: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu you're welcome. I had exactly the same question when I first started using Mma. Have fun:)

Comment: Surely in this case `Table[]`>`For[]`

Comment: @Feyre as you and Mr.Wizard have suggested Table may be natural alternative. I provided link to motivate looking at alternatives.

Comment: @Feyre & ubpdqn Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

*For fun*

### Example

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < n, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 {n, 1, 3, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: e.doroskevic: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu you are most welcome