# Mathematica for Theoretical Physics by Gerd Baumann : Henonmap

Tags: plotting, code-review, compatibility

I was following a solved problem from the book mentioned below on the Henon map. However, even after correcting that I still get an error on execution. I am unable to find the exact cause.

> Mathematica for Theoretical Physics Classical Mechanics and Nonlinear Dynamics by  Gerd Baumann

Here is the code mentioned in the book.

```
JacobiMatrix[fun_List, vars_List] := Outer[D, fun, vars]

Clear[HenonMap]

HenonMap[{T_, W_}, α_] := 
 Block[{}, {θ*Cos[2*π*α] - (W - θ^2)*
     Sin[2*π*α], θ*
     Sin[2*π*α] + (W - θ^2)*Cos[2*π*α]}]

JacobiMatrix[
  HenonMap[{θ, W}, α], {θ, W}] // MatrixForm

JacobiMatrix[HenonMap[{θ, W}, α], {θ, W}] // 
  Det // Simplify

initial = Table[{i, 0, 0}, {i, 0.1, 0.84, 0.015}];

henonPlot = {};

Do[AppendTo[henonPlot, 
  ListPlot[NestList[HenonMap[#, 0.2114] &, initial[[k]], 255], 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[k/Length[initial]], Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "W"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]], {k, 1, Length[initial]}]
```

Comment: @Ghoster, You are right. There is nothing wrong. I misread it. I've edited my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `HenonMap[{T_, W_}, α_]` uses `T` in args but `θ` in body
2. `initial` is 3D, should be 2D

```
JacobiMatrix[fun_List, vars_List] := Outer[D, fun, vars]

Clear[HenonMap]

HenonMap[{T_, W_}, α_] := 
 Block[{}, {T*Cos[2*π*α] - (W - T^2)*
     Sin[2*π*α], T*
     Sin[2*π*α] + (W - T^2)*Cos[2*π*α]}]

JacobiMatrix[
  HenonMap[{θ, W}, α], {θ, W}] // MatrixForm

JacobiMatrix[HenonMap[{θ, W}, α], {θ, W}] // 
  Det // Simplify

initial = Table[{i, 0}, {i, 0.1, 0.84, 0.015}];

henonPlot = {};

Do[AppendTo[henonPlot, 
  ListPlot[NestList[HenonMap[#, 0.2114] &, initial[[k]], 255], 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[k/Length[initial]], Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"θ", "W"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]], {k, 1, Length[initial]}]
   
Show[henonPlot]
```

[image]

Comment: Silly me. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: just one more query, Why is that single loop isn't plotting after the Do[...] as shown in book?

Comment: `Do` doesn't not return values, in this code plots are appended to a list, you need to use `Show` to combine them and show. Using `Table` is more in `WM` style `Show[Table[ListPlot[ ...], {k, 1, Length[initial]}]]`

Comment: @user84456 That's a compatibility issue, `*Plot` functions in and before _v5_ automatically prints the graphic. See this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47123/1871

Comment: @user84456 Which version of Baumann's book are you using? I just checked version 2 of the book, definitions of `HenonMap` and `initial` are both correct therein.