# Creating a multiline function with localized variables

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

I would like to create a function with several expressions in the code body.

For example, I would like to write something like this, but which will actually work.

```
myFunction[x]:=
  y=x
  y=y+3;
  (y+3)^3
```

I know that I can do this :

```
myFunction[x]:=(y=x;y=y+3;(y+3)^3)
```

But it will be hardly writable if I have a lot of expression to evaluate.

How can I do it?

(I just installed Mathematica and read some tutorials on the internet so my knowledge is veeeeeery basic).

Comment: Use `Module[{y},...]` to make `y` a local variable. You can use newlines, they have no syntactical meaning.

Comment: You mean I should write :
`myFunction[x]:=Module[{y},y=x;y=y+3;(y+3)^3]` And I can do newline between my ";" ?

Comment: Take a look http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateDefinitionsForVariablesAndFunctions.html and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39464/5478 for more basic tutorials.

Comment: @Felix in cells they have, unless they are inside expressions.

Comment: Yes, within `Module` (or simply parentheses for that matter) you can use a newline for spacing, but you *still* need `;` (CompoundExpression) or you end up multiplying expressions unintentionally.  Please see [(41091)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41091/121) for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should write your function like so:

```
myFunction[x_] :=
  Module[{y},
    y = x;
    y = y + 3;
    (y + 3)^3]
```

Note the underscore in `x_`. This makes `x` into a formal argument that will not be confused with any definition of x you might have made.

Then, even when `x` and `y` have global values they will not interfere with either the proper definition of `myFunction` nor with calls to it.

```
x = 42; y = 43;
myFunction[1]
```

> `343`

You can read more about defining functions [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html)