# Next line without ";" and set::write error => why?

Tags: warning-messages, core-language

In my code I first wrote :

```
Print["else"]
beta156v345 = 
 1/Sin[theta15]*1/
  Sin[theta35]*(Cos[theta13]*1 - 
    Cos[theta15] Cos[theta35]); (* j1^j5 . j3^j5 *)
```

And it said me a set::write error.

Then I added a ";" after my Print["else"] :

```
 Print["else"];
beta156v345 = 
 1/Sin[theta15]*1/
  Sin[theta35]*(Cos[theta13]*1 - 
    Cos[theta15] Cos[theta35]); (* j1^j5 . j3^j5 *)
```

And there were no longer the error.

Why there had an error in the first time ? I thought that the ";" was only here to say "do not display this" if I have a variable for example. (I just want to understand how mathematica works to be more efficient)

Comment: Is this code contained in a `Module` or other construct?  Only bare lines of code are read as actual lines; those contained in something else need to be separated.  See the example in the middle of my answer to [(41086)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41086/121)

Comment: Indeed it is in a Module. I will take a look, thanks !